# connection failed for: localhost (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am using capistrano 2.15.5 for my rails application deployment. I am using localhost for server and have also tried with 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost. `After running *cap production deploy:setup* the error that i am getting is: **Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)**.`
After searching for it i found out **ECONNREFUSED means the client couldn't make a TCP connection to the server, either because it's down, or its DNS is not resolving.**.

how to fix this issue?
thanks.

Comment: do you need any other server like redis to be started?

Comment: yes i am using redis !!

Comment: then have you started redis-server?

Comment: yes i have started it !!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your ssh key in server's ssh authorize keys